# 16.10 Can't boot (emergency mode) 'swap has failed'

Tags: boot, swap, crash, systemd

my Kubuntu 16.10 doesn't boot anymore. It falls into emergency mode and even after continuing with Ctrl+D it ran emergency mode after exactly 90 sec (also the default timeout for partitions). The only thing I did that may have caused this problem was updating a few packages. Also I have dual-boot with Windows 8.1.

For Information here the output of **fdisk -l** (don't mind the german):

```
Medium /dev/sda: 465,8 GiB, 500107862016 Bytes, 976773168 Sektoren
Einheiten: sectors von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorengröße (logisch/physisch): 512 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
I/O Größe (minimal/optimal): 4096 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
Typ der Medienbezeichnung: gpt
Medienkennung: 1B206445-6D93-4B1F-B5EC-59D0109B40AC

Gerät          Start      Ende  Sektoren  Größe Typ
/dev/sda1       2048    821247    819200   400M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2     821248   1353727    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/sda3    1353728   1615871    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4    1615872 477867489 476251618 227,1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  949127168 976762879  27635712  13,2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda7  940965888 949127167   8161280   3,9G Linux Swap
/dev/sda8  879525888 940965887  61440000  29,3G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda9  477868032 879525887 401657856 191,5G Linux filesystem
```

and **blkid**:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="WINRE" UUID="7E9CBDF59CBDA7D3" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="810a5b07-9711-4037-920e-4ac07f5cc3a3"
/dev/sda2: UUID="E646-E8C5" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="d055411e-8e52-4d44-a69b-64de9cdfb75e"
/dev/sda4: LABEL="Windows" UUID="3628BCF828BCB7E7" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="6aa9d2d7-df51-4df5-b94c-0ce2892cfe56"
/dev/sda5: LABEL="RECOVERY" UUID="3674B87774B83C05" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="76f9d43c-2cbd-4e2e-bfb7-7764ecde33fc"
/dev/sda7: UUID="7526761c-b5a4-4fde-a1d5-672ef7b83b0b" TYPE="swap" PARTLABEL="Swap" PARTUUID="8e24fc33-f43e-4fa8-a664-4b3bf5a376f7"
/dev/sda8: UUID="89aaacd1-1e02-4636-a601-08be42fd29f5" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="System" PARTUUID="acdd51a1-aeb5-4051-90af-d436eea9b618"
/dev/sda9: UUID="4470c52f-b60e-4301-bd09-3eafb6de7d65" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Home" PARTUUID="6c777510-50f5-49bd-b27f-3ac6da4c2778"
/dev/sda3: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="191bea73-7541-4428-8650-def9849b28ed"
```

and **journalctl -xb | grep swap**:

```
Apr 03 21:19:47 gabriel-kubuntu-16 kernel: zswap: loaded using pool lzo/zbud
-- Subject: Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-7526761c\x2db5a4\x2d4fde\x2da1d5\x2d672ef7b83b0b.swap has failed
-- Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-7526761c\x2db5a4\x2d4fde\x2da1d5\x2d672ef7b83b0b.swap has failed.
-- Subject: Unit swap.target has failed
-- Unit swap.target has failed.
Apr 03 21:19:47 gabriel-kubuntu-16 systemd[1]: swap.target: Job swap.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Apr 03 21:19:47 gabriel-kubuntu-16 systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-7526761c\x2db5a4\x2d4fde\x2da1d5\x2d672ef7b83b0b.swap: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-7526761c\x2db5a4\x2d4fde\x2da1d5\x2d672ef7b83b0b.swap/start failed with result 'dependency'.
-- Subject: Unit dev-sda7.swap has failed
-- Unit dev-sda7.swap has failed.
Apr 03 21:21:17 gabriel-kubuntu-16 systemd[1]: dev-sda7.swap: Job dev-sda7.swap/start failed with result 'dependency'.
```

...because all errors in journalctl were concerning the swap.

*EDIT:* There are two sections in journalctl that are looking bad:

```
Apr 03 21:19:47 gabriel-kubuntu-16 systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-7526761c\x2db5a4\x2d4fde\x2da1d5\x2d672ef7b83b0b.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-7526761c\x2db5a4\x2d4fde\x2da1d5\x2d672ef7b83b0b.device/start timed out.
Apr 03 21:19:47 gabriel-kubuntu-16 systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-7526761c\x2db5a4\x2d4fde\x2da1d5\x2d672ef7b83b0b.device.
-- Subject: Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-7526761c\x2db5a4\x2d4fde\x2da1d5\x2d672ef7b83b0b.device has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-7526761c\x2db5a4\x2d4fde\x2da1d5\x2d672ef7b83b0b.device has failed.
-- 
-- The result is timeout.
Apr 03 21:19:47 gabriel-kubuntu-16 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /dev/disk/by-uuid/7526761c-b5a4-4fde-a1d5-672ef7b83b0b.
-- Subject: Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-7526761c\x2db5a4\x2d4fde\x2da1d5\x2d672ef7b83b0b.swap has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-7526761c\x2db5a4\x2d4fde\x2da1d5\x2d672ef7b83b0b.swap has failed.
-- 
-- The result is dependency.
Apr 03 21:19:47 gabriel-kubuntu-16 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Swap.
-- Subject: Unit swap.target has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit swap.target has failed.
-- 
-- The result is dependency.
Apr 03 21:19:47 gabriel-kubuntu-16 systemd[1]: swap.target: Job swap.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Apr 03 21:19:47 gabriel-kubuntu-16 systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-7526761c\x2db5a4\x2d4fde\x2da1d5\x2d672ef7b83b0b.swap: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-7526761c\x2db5a4\x2d4fde\x2da1d5\x2d672ef7b83b0b.swap/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Apr 03 21:19:47 gabriel-kubuntu-16 systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-7526761c\x2db5a4\x2d4fde\x2da1d5\x2d672ef7b83b0b.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-7526761c\x2db5a4\x2d4fde\x2da1d5\x2d672ef7b83b0b.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
```

and

```
Apr 03 21:21:17 gabriel-kubuntu-16 systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-E646\x2dE8C5.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-E646\x2dE8C5.device/start timed out.
Apr 03 21:21:17 gabriel-kubuntu-16 systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-E646\x2dE8C5.device.
-- Subject: Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-E646\x2dE8C5.device has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-E646\x2dE8C5.device has failed.
-- 
-- The result is timeout.
Apr 03 21:21:17 gabriel-kubuntu-16 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/E646-E8C5.
-- Subject: Unit systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-E646\x2dE8C5.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-E646\x2dE8C5.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is dependency.
Apr 03 21:21:17 gabriel-kubuntu-16 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /boot/efi.
-- Subject: Unit boot-efi.mount has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit boot-efi.mount has failed.
-- 
-- The result is dependency.
Apr 03 21:21:17 gabriel-kubuntu-16 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
-- Subject: Unit local-fs.target has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit local-fs.target has failed.
-- 
-- The result is dependency.
Apr 03 21:21:17 gabriel-kubuntu-16 systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Job local-fs.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Apr 03 21:21:17 gabriel-kubuntu-16 systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
Apr 03 21:21:17 gabriel-kubuntu-16 systemd[1]: boot-efi.mount: Job boot-efi.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Apr 03 21:21:17 gabriel-kubuntu-16 systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-E646\x2dE8C5.service: Job systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-E646\x2dE8C5.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Apr 03 21:21:17 gabriel-kubuntu-16 systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-E646\x2dE8C5.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-E646\x2dE8C5.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
Apr 03 21:21:17 gabriel-kubuntu-16 systemd[1]: dev-sda7.device: Job dev-sda7.device/start timed out.
Apr 03 21:21:17 gabriel-kubuntu-16 systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-sda7.device.
-- Subject: Unit dev-sda7.device has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit dev-sda7.device has failed.
-- 
-- The result is timeout.
Apr 03 21:21:17 gabriel-kubuntu-16 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Swap Partition.
-- Subject: Unit dev-sda7.swap has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit dev-sda7.swap has failed.
-- 
-- The result is dependency.
Apr 03 21:21:17 gabriel-kubuntu-16 systemd[1]: dev-sda7.swap: Job dev-sda7.swap/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Apr 03 21:21:17 gabriel-kubuntu-16 systemd[1]: dev-sda7.device: Job dev-sda7.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
```

Here my **/etc/fstab**:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=89aaacd1-1e02-4636-a601-08be42fd29f5 /               ext4  defaults,noauto,nofail,errors=remount-ro   0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=E646-E8C5  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda9 during installation
UUID=4470c52f-b60e-4301-bd09-3eafb6de7d65 /home           ext4  defaults,noauto,nofail,errors=remount-ro   0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=7526761c-b5a4-4fde-a1d5-672ef7b83b0b none            swap  sw         0      0
```

I already tried changing a few options in the fstab and running fsck on the partitions from a live usb. After looking at the journalctl the error is probably located at the swap partition sda7, so I formated and rebuilt it. But nothing changed. 
Does anybody know what's wrong and how I can fix the problem??

Comment: Did you format and rebuild sda7 using gparted? Did you tell it to initialize it as swap? Did the UUID change, and then you had to edit /etc/fstab? Did you ever use a mkswap command? What is the result of a `swapon` and `free -h` commands?

Comment: Instead of grep'ing the journal for swap, review the full `journalctl` output and search for the most recent mentions of "swap". Then look for nearby logs that may be related. For example, the logs you shared show that a dependency failed, but no logs are included related to what that dependency was.

Comment: I formated the swap as ext4 first, then with mkswap from the command line. Then I mounted it, put the new UUID in /etc/fstab and /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume and ran `sudo update-initramfs -u`. swapon says it's okay and I can use the swap from my ubuntu live-usb.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a working solution so now I just reinstalled Kubuntu and upgraded to 17.04 to make it worth it. Now everything works fine again and I hope this error won't come back at any time :D